# Vader is immune to laser beams?

Tags: realism, star-wars

Ok, I just noticed this: Han Solo shoots laser beams at Darth Vader who apparently is completely immune. Ok, so if Jedi are immune to laser beams, why even bother to deflect them with a light saber? Or I am just asking a ridiculous question?

[image]

Comment: He is wearing armour...

Comment: Vader deflects them without a lightsaber - he’s not blanket immune. Luke either doesn’t have that power yet or it’s more of a dark side thing. Vader is not a Jedi. There’s no reason to think anything true about Vader is true about Jedi.

Comment: Lets not forget, in episode 7 Ren I think basically suspends a laser bolt in mid-air. Seems the force (whether light/dark/whatever) can be used to affect laser bolts, but chances are it's not really practical in the middle of a battle (may require too much effort, especially if there's lots of them).

Comment: Blaster bolts, not laser beams.

Comment: armor or not, he is "wearing" *robot hands*

Comment: @Yorik Blaster fire, especially that from Han's heavy modified blaster, will damage machined parts.

Comment: Related: (Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE) [Did Vader deflect, absorb or block Solo's blaster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/84611/7957)

Answer (score 9):

When Vader turns away Han's heavy blaster fire in the Cloud City dining room, he is doing so by will of his Force, not armor.  He very well could have used his saber for this purpose, but the manner in which he does (stopping with his palm) is meant to induce fear and render his attackers helpless by that fear.

Answer (score 1):

### Vader's hands are not real

Darth Vader is mostly a cyborg and his hands were cut off and replaced with mechanical ones. These have obviously been hardened against blaster fire. Remember in ROTJ during the sail barge scene, Luke also gets shot in the hand with a blaster and the only effect is the fake skin is burned away.

Comment: Um.  And his gloves?  His gloves are not blaster retardant.